# Azure Cloud Services not logging ASP.NET errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Using cloud services and the Azure 2.0 SDK, I would like to have my ASP.NET errors get logged to the Azure Diagnostics service.

In Visual Studio, there's a section under Diagnostics Summary called 
"Windows Azure Application Logs"
Also
"Event Logs"

When I hit an error, I only see the standard 500 error page, but there is no log anywhere to show it.

I do not want to see the yellow screen of death (since this is a customer facing page)

I'd expect that I could either open one of those Azure Tables or Blobs, and see stack traces for my ASP.NET errors (such as Null Reference Exceptions, Entity Framework errors, etc)

How do I configure this to work with Azure SDK 2.0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Windows Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx) does not include stack traces in their diagnostics.

But, you could use the same tracing strategy used in your regular web apps (aka, [System.Diagnostics.Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)). [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411529.aspx) gives you more information about how to use them in Windows Azure., or use libraries like [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (this is a great logging library that gives you a lot of information about the error, including FORM values!).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Azure Cloud Services Web Role project, open the properties for the web role.
2. Turn on **Enable Diagnostics** and choose **Custom plan**, and click **Edit**.
3. From the **Log directories** tab select your desired transfer period and click **OK**.
4. In Solution Explorer, expand the tree node for your web role, and open `diagnostics.wadcfg`.
5. Add this line to the `Directories` element:

   ```xml
   <FailedRequestLogs container="wad-frq" directoryQuotaInMB="512" />
   ```
6. In `web.config`, add the following under the `system.webServer` element:

   ```xml
   <tracing>
     <traceFailedRequests>
       <add path="*">
         <traceAreas>
           <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
           <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication, Security, Filter, StaticFile, CGI, Compression, Cache, RequestNotifications, Module" verbosity="Verbose" />
         </traceAreas>
         <failureDefinitions statusCodes="400-599" />
       </add>
     </traceFailedRequests>
   </tracing>
   ```

Changes to `diagnostics.wadcfg` in your local project don't get applied when redeploying to an existing web role instance. However, deploying to a new staging instance and then swapping works fine.

---

The documentation on this is fragmented:

- [How To Enable Diagnostics in a Cloud Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn482131.aspx), in the section **IIS Failed Request Trace Logs**, describes the XML configurations.
- [Configuring Diagnostics for Azure Cloud Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn186185.aspx) describes the Azure SDK GUI that creates most of `diagnostics.wadcfg` for you, so you don't need to read everything in "How To Enable Diagnostics in a Cloud Service".